# Unable to use body values in INSERT statement

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser, node-odbc

I have a post route that expects to be sent body value name to be supplied in JSON format.

My server.js includes:

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
```

Here is an how the route looks:

```
router.post('/',
[
    check('name', 'Name is required!')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
],
async (req, res) => {
    const validationErrors = validationResult(req);
    if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ validationErrors: validationErrors.array() });
    }
    else {
        try {
            await odbc.connect(cn, (error, connection) => {
                console.log(req.body.name)
                connection.query(
                    "INSERT INTO test.amessages(name) VALUES(:req.body.name)",
                    (error, result) => {
                        if (error) {
                            throw error;
                        }
                        return res.status(200).json({ result });
                    }
                );
            });

        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server Error' });
        }
    }
});
```

The console.log before the variable gives me the correct value supplied to the route. Typically when using other tools that target sqlserver I have been able to put in ${req.body.name} and that would work. In this case that and the following have not worked - (req.body.name), :req.body.name, (req.body.name) and other various combinations.

Here is a look at how I am supplying the values to the route:

```
{
    "name": "Test"
}
```

How can I utilize the body values in the Insert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc#querysql-parameters-callback-1) you can pass a paramter array to the `query`-function which will be bound to the `?` values:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO test.amessages(name) VALUES(?)",
                    // actually with the json you provided it seems you rather want to use req.body.name
                    [req.body.test],
                    (error, result) => {
                        if (error) {
                            throw error;
                        }
                        return res.status(200).json({ result });
                    }
                );
```

Comment: Thanks EOL the console.log before my insert statement was incorrect. Had to make changes to the code so it wasnt the same as production and I didnt name it properly. Fixed it in the question. Working on implementing your changes now. I will let you know how it works.

Comment: That works! Cant believe I missed that in the documentation. Only question I have remaining  is what if you have 2 values in your parameter array [req.body.test, req.body.job]? For instance what it I wanted to do this?  "INSERT INTO test.amessages(name, job) VALUES(?) How do you differentiate between those 2 values with the ?. Like ?.req.body.test and ?.req.body.job?

Comment: Yes ` [req.body.test, req.body.job]` looks fine, just add another place holder in the query: `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(?, ?)` - the values will be bound according to their occurence/order in the params-array.

Comment: Thanks! for all your help. I am new to db2 and that particular package, the documentation was a bit overwhelming for me, but ill make a better effort of going through it next time before posting a question.